# Introduce a better way to identify trusted users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, trusted-user

Stack Overflow depends heavily on moderation by a body of reliable users dedicated to the *site* rather than merely gaining points and badges any way possible. It's vital to be able to tell these groups apart from each other.

Over time, reputation is going to become less and less reliable a way to do that. The voting system is easy to game, in many ways and shades. There are contributors rising "through the ranks" whose main motivation is not creating a high quality resource. They just post mediocre stuff in popular tags. Eventually, they *will* reach hundreds of thousands of rep.

The recent problems with the review queue show that **there should be a better way of telling apart users genuinely concerned with quality from those just hanging out to earn rep and badges.**

Now, machines and algorithms can always be gamed. The best detectors of dedicated users who are "for real" would arguably be - you and me! The dedicated, veteran users. In our everyday interactions on SO and maybe Meta, we come across fellow users and, over time, reach some judgement of them and their actions on the site. I could probably name fifty users right away who I would absolutely trust using the  review queue. I could also find fifty users who I would *absolutely not* trust using the review queue.

Currently, there is no way for me to explicitly tell the system that I trust or distrust these users. Voting doesn't work for this: I may not be active in the same tags as them, or they may not be answering much on SO in the first place, but be busy editing and commenting. Or the bulk of their activity will be on Meta. Or I will know them personally from conferences and such, rather than the site itself. And one vote is only a drop in the bike-shed-ridden bucket anyway.

Should SO create a new, mostly invisible, social layer of trust? A way for a user to tell the system whether they trust a user or not. Obviously implemented in a way that doesn't break the basic SO idea of "it's about the content, not the users".

There are many ways to do this. Most are horribly flawed. There must absolutely not be any kind of public showing off of "trust rates" or something.

One way that might suck slightly less than all the others is a simple yes/no system.

A user would become a trusted user when they receive enough votes of confidence, let's call them "trust votes", from *other trusted users*. A number of trust votes is required to make you a trusted user, depending on how trusted the voters are. A moderator trust vote could make you trusted immediately. The algorithms used to calculate trustworthiness, and the threshold at which you yourself become trusted, would be secret. Votes of confidence would remain anonymous, so you never know how many people voted for you and who.

Once a user becomes a trusted user, the words "trusted user" would show up in their profile; no other public recognition is given.

[image: picture of a profile, with the words "trusted user" next to the username]

The trusted user status gives them access to certain moderation tools that are closed to everyone else, even 20k+ users. (To me, the review queue should be one of them.) New moderation tools could become "trusted only" instead of 5k+, 10k+, 20k+ tools. (Migrating some existing privileges to "trusted only" would probably be too unfriendly an act to those who'd stand to lose it that way.)

Users would have a "I trust this person" / "I do not trust this person" button when they visit another user's profile. A trust vote is an important thing and people would have to be encouraged to use their votes wisely. Maybe through a total limit that you have to manage carefully, and that grows very slowly (say, five new votes a month).

As to how to get this whole thing started: at first, give, say, 50 trust votes to a limited circle. The ideal circle would be  the people who have undergone the most scrutiny by the community, and are best equipped to have a good impression of users' activities: **the moderators**.

Let it spread from there, like a ponzi scheme, moderators trust-voting users, and those again trust-voting others - although maybe with less votes than the initial allotment that the moderators get. This would my favourite method of starting it because the feature would remain very low-key this way.

To reiterate, this is as non-social as can be. **There is no public display of how many people trust you. You never know how many people trust or distrust you, and who they are.** All that is visible to you and the public is the info whether you are a trusted user.

Making sure that only other trusted users can make you a trusted user help prevent "awesome, this user gave me the codez so I vote to trust him in return" situations. This suggestion is explicitly designed to battle bike shed voting by limiting the number of people who *can* vote.

Things that would have to be addressed:

- Users from tags with little traffic might go unrecognized, as there are fewer people to observe and appreciate their activity.
- There would have to be the possibility to withdraw "trusted user" status. Most likely if you gain a lot of negative trust votes. This would have to be dealt with carefully.

Comment: A Ponzi scheme breaks down if people don't continue putting money into it. What happens if the second / third layer of people only use a fraction of their votes?

Comment: Ha, we were just whining and moaning about this in our mod chat room an hour ago. On a site like SO, reputation is no longer a reliable measure of how much the community trusts you in terms of community moderation, but merely in terms of knowledge in the subject matter (i.e. programming).

Comment: @Ben my thinking is that the existence of the feature itself would be enough to encourage people to trust-vote a lot, and the main challenge would be making sure they don't vote *too much*. It's like a tiny moderator election that runs every day - I'm not worried about attendance. One would have to see how it works out in the real world, though, of course.

Comment: @Bolt yeah, and sometimes not even that. You can easily "get rich" by posting 20 cheap jQuery or PHP snippets a day.

Comment: @Pekka: That too :(

Comment: Can we expect users to behave/think differently when using this separate voting system?

Comment: @Pekka This isn't the first time I'm getting the feeling you _somehow_ have found a way to spy on us in Teacher's Lounge ;P

Comment: @Ludo I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean users at large thinking about how to *receive* trust votes, or people casting their vote?

Comment: @Yannis heh, funny! No, I have no special access. Except maybe through psychic means. :)

Comment: I'm mostly referring to your second paragraph. How would a separate voting system address these issues? But I do understand how skills and trust are different things tho.

Comment: @Ludo only trusted users could cast trusted user votes, it wouldn't be a community-wide thing. That would prevent it from becoming a pure "Like / dislike" popularity contest. Plus you'd have a limited number of votes that you have to use wisely, and only on those users you feel most strongly about either way. I expect people would use ther vote more like a vote in a mod election, than like an everyday vote on content

Comment: One more objection before I upvote :-). I would be worried that the trusted user group quickly becomes a closed circle. Say, no pressure :-), I vote for you and you vote for me. Would it make sense to give trusted users an additional vote a month, say?

Comment: @Ben re tags, that is an issue. A lone hero could be doing great work in some obscure tag but never become a trusted user because nobody sees it. That would have to be addressed somehow. Re the circle-jerk/country club thing, yes, that would be bound to happen to some extent. The Meta crowd trust-voting each other etc. But I trust that it won't be much of a problem: most users on Meta *are* genuine concerned users, and if you are active on SO proper, you will know people doing good work there that aren't in any of your social circles. If I had 10 trust votes, I could name right away...

Comment: ... 10 people that aren't active on Meta at all, and that I have never even spoken to. So I expect voting would easily go beyond your own circles. And remember there isn't much public recognition - you never know who trust-voted you, and there are no badges and fancy numbers to show off. Plus, one vote will not be enough to push a user over the threshold.

Comment: +1 for the question, but I don't know how I feel about "trusted" as a *boolean* value

Comment: @Jeroen yeah, treating "trusted" like how flag weight works (as a float value) might be a way to go as well, but then you'd have a number that can go up and down, with all the associated drama. I wanted to avoid that. But an approach where the trust value is shown to no one, and used only for internal calculations, would be a valid counter-suggestion.

Comment: Wow, Google Image search has some rather... literal results for "circle jerk" when you have safe search turned off. Okay, no illustrations for this post!

Comment: What did you expect @Pekka, unicorns and waffles :-). I don't believe that Meta has corrupted you _that_ much!

Comment: I think that the term `Trusted User` might be incorrectly associated with the content that the users might post as answers and not necessarily be associated with the users' review/moderation patterns on the site content itself.

Comment: @Siva I'd say that's what's happening right now, with reputation being the sole basis for what tools users get access to. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I meant the display of `Trusted User` in your screenshot on the user profile page might be interpreted incorrectly by some. If someone notices that a user is trusted, they might assume that everything that they post in a particular tag is absolutely correct. We need a different word. I hope that I am not confusing.

Comment: @Siva ahh, I see. Fair point. I *was* thinking about a hover that explains what the label is about, but maybe it indeed needs a better one.

Comment: @Pekka Make it say "Trusted Janitor".

Comment: But still you could have sock puppets voting you for trusted user/janitor :P to get that additional vote/privilege.

Comment: @2-Stroker: No, you need to be a trusted user yourself, in order to vote for others being trusted.

Comment: -1 This looks like an overreaction to the problems introduced by the review queue. Creating an elitist ponzi-scheme system like this one *might* solve the review queue problems, but it will further aggravate other problems. It is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @Null it's not really a reaction to those problems specifically - the issue of trust not being equal to high rep is there anyway, and is likely to become more and more relevant. I actually had the idea for this a year or two ago.

Comment: @Pekka One *immediate* problem I see with this is that it will create an unfairly privileged group: one that will have the same tendencies and ideas when it comes to closing and deleting questions. It will be hard for someone who does indeed care about the site, but just thinks differently (ie: an inclusionist vs. a majority of exclusionists) to become a "trusted" user.  This will further tip the scale in favor of one group, and promote more divisiveness in the community.

Comment: @Null I'm not sure trusted voting would necessarily have that effect. Sure, some dedicated groups of users will vote each other in, but the general population is much larger than that. Also I doubt whether a lot of voting will strictly follow these ideological lines. A lot would be down to how moderators "seed" the initial votes.

Comment: @Pekka Yeah, but if I understand correctly you also want the ability to vote someone *out*, right? And there lies the problem. If the way some questions are getting closed and deleted is any indication (ie: by the same group of people, who will very likely find their way into this "trusted" circle), this will open a huge can of worms.

Comment: @Null yes, that's why I said  `This would have to be dealt with carefully.` - a single "untrust" vote must never kick someone out, but "gang warfare" style voting is a possibility. How to deal with that is an unsolved question. Maybe voting people *out* would need to be reserved for the most egregious cases...

Comment: I agree but I think this is not possible. People always find ways to become popular without being good... Look at pop singers or politicians (exceptions reserved to both groups).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Once upon a time, votes for questions and votes for answers received the same ten points. Time passed, and an ever-growing number of people were reaching important rep thresholds based on questions -- and, to make it worse, often they were crowd- (or Fiddler-) pleasing fun or fluff.

Two responses ensued: less reputation for question votes, and clearer guidelines encouraging closure and deletion of fluff.

However, rep, like entropy, is ever-increasing. Even with less points for a question, a user who just posts a lot of fair-to-middling questions will eventually reach any threshold.

This question, however, challenges a more basic assumption. A core theory of this site was that editorial privileges should be gated by expertise, as measured by rep. Give or take the edit review system, which only functions at the low end, janatorial efforts are rewarded entirely by badges, while janatorial privileges are awarded based on content.

Changing this would be radical, in the original, root-vegetable, sense of that word. I'm afraid that this proposal would add a confusing mechanism that might not, in the end, fix things.

I submit that 'trust-votes' are, essentially, a continuous, larger-scale, moderator election. As such, this proposal should be considered, pondered, and perhaps modified in the light of expanding the moderator system.

The problem I see is that the actions that *should* feed an evaluation of granting privileges are not very visible. What users can *see* of my actions are my answers, comments, and edits, and close votes. They can't see my flags or plain old votes.

Ideally, the system would observe my *proposals* for actions (e.g. flags), and grant me autonomy based on whether my proposals meet with the approval of the mods.

In other words, instead of asking users to trust me based on questionably relevant evidence, the system should decide to trust me by measuring entirely relevant metrics. If my flags are nearly always right, I should be trusted more to do these things. I don't claim to have a completely worked-out proposal here, but I submit the general idea for consideration.

Comment: Very fair points. I agree that this would amount to the election of thousands of junior moderators. Approaching this from the other end (ie. changing the mod system) might indeed make more sense

Comment: well, the core issue is that we are measuring two things: 1. skill at programming (or {site topic}, say photography) 2. skill at moderating -- but we are granting incremental moderator abilities solely based on #1 and *not at all* based on #2, which *mostly* works but isn't really correct in the big scheme of things.

Comment: @JeffAtwood indeed that is a concise restatement of my point.

Answer (score 41):

I began noticing some *very* odd voting shortly after the new review system was implemented. Normally, when I see a completely *craptastic* post with several up votes, I run straight to our tools to see if I notice any suspicious patterns. After chasing half a dozen geese, I realized that it's just people blindly voting in review.

There's also more users that write .. less than awesome posts now reviewing .. less than awesome posts. So it's not always blind gamification, ignorance is partially to blame.

What remains is, those that *can* maintain high quality and *do* participate in review flag this stuff, and we take action. So a *partial* solution, or perhaps the means of getting data to come up *with* a solution is this:

*Track the amount of negative actions a moderator or trusted (20k) user took on a post any user positively reviewed, by the user(s) that reviewed it.*

This should quickly be able to tell us who is doing it wrong, which leads to a better idea of what (if anything) could be done about it. I really want better data on the problem before anything is done to correct it.

Comment: Not sure if it's related to the new review system, but recently I've seen several bad questions with upvotes. And with bad I mean that they're incomprehensible/unanswerable.

Comment: @CodesInChaos yup, I'm fairly sure that is 100% tied to the review system.

Comment: This is probably the consequence of including voting as possible action that removes a post from a review queue. As users feel they are doing a good job by limiting the grown of the review queues, some of them will accept voting as needed action, even if the post doesn't really deserve any up-vote.

Comment: Another great example of the bizarre voting that review badge gaming has caused is this link-only answer promoting a user's blog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498357/move-circle-when-user-touch-on-the-circle-in-android/13210739#13210739 that was upvoted 4 times in under a minute this morning. If moderators had better metrics on who was possibly reviewing poorly (upvoted posts that were later deleted, accept votes that run contrary to three reject votes on a suggested edit, etc.), we could look over those reviews ourselves and maybe nudge people in the right direction.

Comment: @Brad nudge... or slap :) I'm starting to think you could post the first few paragraphs of *Das Kapital* as a question on Stack Overflow, and under the right conditions it could get a couple of upvotes.

Comment: I considered posting about 'one second reviews' or 'who reviews the reviewers' but the issue is basically covered here. One idea is to have the option to veto a review. If a review gets N vetos (number of vetos already cast will not be shown) the review won't count. If a user gets many reviews veto'd, s/he could be temporarily banned from reviewing. This may encourage some to actually review posts instead of just up-voting through them for whatever reason.

Comment: Well, part of the problem with the review queue is it forces you to upvote or downvote or do something, when quite frankly, not every post needs something be done with it. So perhaps a lot of people are upvoting as a default measure?

Comment: Of course. The issue i am referring to is upvoting blindly, as in processing several reviews in just a few seconds. If there was an option to just accept as-is, certain ppl would use that instead of upvoting, without actually reviewing the post. Possibly to get badges or because the post looks 'well formatted' when you look at it for only a second. I don't know if this happens frequently and just goes unnoticed except for extreme cases. Also there are many different opinions on what's considered proper reviewing.

Comment: @jmort253: exactly the case.

Answer (score 10):

The idea is interesting, but the thing is, people actually *vote* on posts. People spend a great deal of time going to posts and they generally remember to upvote them if they're good; it's a pretty natural interaction on the web. Going to people's profiles after getting certain magic votes and giving special magic person votes? Let's sanity check that quick.

People don't visit profile pages often. (Limiting factor 1) Profile pages are really busy, so a new button would be hard to notice (limiting factor 2) and some major education stuff would be needed (limiting factor 3). To boot, only "trusted users" are allowed to vote (limiting factor 4). If there's only so many trusted users, it's *really* easy for the system to break down if just a few people don't vote. And what if we're talking about Stack Overflow? Suddenly tag partitions are a big problem; trusted users like John Skeet and Eric Lippert might be great at identifying Trusted users in C# (if they care), but they're unlikely to see trusted users in tags they don't use, or worse, ignore (limiting factor 5).

The suggested method of starting this off (moderators voting) sounds bad too, in no small part because of the potential for drama. Suddenly I, as a moderator, am supposed to decide who gets privileges on the site. I'm sure you see the potential problem there.

On top of all of the things that *drastically* limit the likelyhood anyone will actually vote here, suddenly we're voting on people, not posts. With the exception of moderator elections, that's a pretty big paradigm shift.

The problem really shouldn't be judging the quality of *users* directly and subjectively like this. If anything a user's *actions* should be judged. If a user consistently approves edits that are rejected or makes edits that are rolled back, maybe they should get a notification or maybe even a brief approval/edit ban. But the whole thing where an extremely limited set of people are expected to vote on an extremely limited set of people via an extremely rare action just seems like an extremely good way to make sure we just plain don't have anyone that can actually use these tools.

If there's a problem with how people use a tool, address that. That's why we have edit bans, require multiple approvals, multiple close votes, etc. Just making a system so that virtually no one can ever use it just makes tools useless and forces the burden back on moderators who are already spread thin. The whole point of community trust and community moderation abilities is to lighten the load of moderators and make moderation a thing *everyone* can take part of, not just the 0.0001% of people who actually recieved or cast these new magic votes.

Comment: I agree.  In addition, I think we'll find that no matter what the rules are, there will be people who will game the system to appear better that others (higher rep, getting trusted, etc.). What's to keep some folks from making their friends trusted users regardless of their actual skills or dedication to the site?

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea. As [jokerdino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153506/179419) says there ought to be some mitigating factors but I would like to address the potential problems. I think they can be, at least partially, solved by the bit you edited out about allowing everyone to vote and what remains, i.e. starting with a trusted circle.

To avoid the *"circle jerk"* phenomenon I would start, as you suggest, with the moderators. Give each moderator unlimited votes. Once a moderator has nominated you, you're automatically "trusted".

Every trusted user then gets a *limited* number of votes. For example, 12 to start and then one a month. The point of this is for it to be a *low* number. People should be jealous of their votes so they're less likely to use them unwisely. It would make sense for the first batch to have more votes to spread the love around a little more.

It takes X votes from trusted users in order for yourself to become trusted, say 2.

Then to up the chances of ensuring that all tags are covered you allow *everyone* to vote. To stop everyone becoming trusted you still have to be nominated by one trusted user. You also need Y votes from other users. In other words you become trusted if you have the following:

- Y votes from "ordinary" users *and* one vote from a trusted user.
- OR X votes from trusted users.
- OR 1 vote from a moderator.

There could be a little list somewhere of people who need a single vote from a trusted user in order to become "trusted".

A trusted user would also get 1 "untrust" user vote each month. It would require another Z votes from trusted users for someone to become no longer trusted. Moderators would be included in this but would have unlimited votes (no accusations of revenge attacks).

Where I would differ from you is that in time, I think it would be worth applying this to the review queues (in the future). I'm not saying that you have to be a trusted user to use them necessarily but that you would have to have been voted as a trusted user by a few not yet trusted users in order to use them.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly how I envisioned how the process could work, but spelled out much clearer. Thanks! One exception: I am in favour of leaving the general public completely out of the equation (ie. only moderators and trusted voters can trust vote), to avoid the thing descending into a popularity contest, and the bike shed effect that normal voting suffers from.

Comment: When moderators don't have limits in doing something, they are also supposed to use that possibility when strictly necessary. Moderators don't have limits on the number of closed questions, but they are supposed to vote to close when strictly necessary (e.g. blatantly off-topic, not constructive, not a real question, or too localized questions). As moderator, I much prefer having something I can do as normal user; I prefer keeping my 40 daily votes, rather than being called out because I voted 100 posts.

Comment: Hmmm, yes @pekka. Without knowledge of how close someone is to being trusted and with the additional restriction that no matter how much you vote for them it'll make no difference without a trusted user coming along _and_ the fact that you have limited votes I think including the general public might be okay. There's enough restrictions that it's impossible to do damage.

Comment: Fair enough @kiamlaluno, it's something that could be restricted after a while. On the larger sites I think that it's something that would need to spread a bit before it's useful but once that's happened mods could easily be restricted as ordinary users are without it hurting the site.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think this idea on a whole is misguided.

The purpose of reputation is to fairly and dispassionately measure "trust" for how SE defines it. With this system, we might as well scrap reputation entirely. And it sets up an awful precedent: if certain people don't like who is at the top of the proverbial "trust" meter, scrap it until we come up with a system that matches those people's [truthy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness) idea of who should be trusted.

But I wanted to highlight one part of your proposal:

> As to how to get this whole thing started: at first, give, say, 50 trust votes to a limited circle. The ideal circle would be the people who have undergone the most scrutiny by the community, and are best equipped to have a good impression of users' activities: **the moderators.**

One of the great benefits of Stack Exchange and how it even bills itself is that the community runs the sites, not them. Why would you cede this amount of power to a set of people who are elected for life?

For that matter, any time the moderators are asked to do a little more, they push back saying that they don't have time or that they're overworked or that they're just volunteers. Why would any moderator agree to this plan? Having to be solely responsible for deciding who is trusted on a site? If a moderator is overworked or has better things to do, this seems like a real hassle.

I get that you don't like how the review queue is going; I really do. But effectively scrapping the reputation system and ceding a huge amount of power to a select group of people  is not the solution.

Rather, the problems you describe can easily be attributed to two things:

- Tools that could use some improvement, because it's too easy to do bad stuff and too difficult to undo aforementioned bad stuff
- A largely disinterested user base who haven't, as yet, found a reason to take the review queues as seriously as people like you do

Instead of writing off the tools and creating a far smaller pool of users helping with community moderation, I'd much rather see the tools improve and ideas on how to get the community more engaged.

Comment: Scrap the reputation system? Holy cow, no. Just limit access to some review and (in the future) other tools, and maybe add small things here and here. My point is, rep as a measure of trust is broken. Being a 20k user no longer necessarily means you are trusted by the community. Even [blankman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/39677/blankman?tab=questions&sort=newest) is approaching 20k, and he hasn't managed to learn the basics of how the site works in 4 years. Not that he'd likely be interested in using the tools, but.... Re seeding, Mods would really be the ideal starting point IMO. It ...

Comment: ... wouldn't mean they have to appoint every trusted user themselves. All that said, I can't really disagree with your last sentence!

Comment: @Pekka The [only practical purpose of the reputation system](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) is to measure trust; to dole out privileges based on the only thing that truly matters on a Q&A site: the ability to post quality content. By removing that purpose and giving it instead to a small group people to subjectively decide who gets access, there's no point to having reputation anymore. But I don't believe SE has become too complex to be managed by self-rule and needs an elite group of people to manage it for us.

Comment: @pekka I agree this is a misguided effort. See my comment on Rosinante's answer here which is quite good.

Comment: @Jeff fair enough. Can you give it a `status-declined` then? I'LL BE KING OF THE TAG YET!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Trusted users are probably, and hopefully folk who have put in a certain degree of community involvement. Considering that one of the things that @Pekka is proposing for the "trusted user" status is having access to the review queue, could I propose that one of the criteria for this would be a reasonable number of  helpful flags (say 50), and at least a 70-80% ratio of helpful to non helpful flags - this means the user takes the effort to flag (and 50 isn't *that* hard).

And while using mods to 'seed' trusted users is a good idea, I think allowing a mod veto/revocation of the trusted user status would be a good balance against it. A large number of negative flags (of unknown amount) by distinct users might be grounds for a review of the status (automating it somewhat).

What I find problematic is the blackbox nature of this. While it prevents the system from being gamed, it feels someone against the whole open nature of the site. Its something that needs to be balanced pretty well.

Comment: Much like flags are anonymous, I don't see a problem with this system being anonymous based. Because this is a question of trust, the algorithm shouldn't be revealed.

Comment: Independently from this suggestion, The "valid flags"  requirement could be an immediate remedy for the /review brokenness.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the idea behind the suggestion but I would like to propose some minor alterations, which I guess would make the idea a teeny bit better.

- The trustees should not have a permanent seat like the moderators. This would help us control the damage in case any user goes rogue and undetected. Each user may have a term of 30 days or so with any significant lapses of judgment costing their position.
- Going with your original idea of allocating votes to already trusted users, any user who  accumulates a certain number of anti-trust votes cannot be appointed as a trusted user for, say 6 months or so. If someone is not trusted by quite a number of people, that should be a good enough indicator.
- Given [subtle hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator) that the community team is overwhelmed with monitoring all 300+ community moderators across the network, it might be wise not to grant insta-votes to trusted users. Instead two votes from any trusted user can be considered final, which would make the body of trusted users self-regulatory and a safer solution.

Comment: This is unworkable... the moderators have enough to do - and their own lives ( I assume :-) ), without having to elect several hundred/thousand users.

Comment: Right~ Poor moderators have a life too. I overlooked that bit. I'll update my post.

Comment: I must say I'm not that worried about circle-jerks - you could say they kind of are the point of the suggestion. I know user X on Meta; I'll trust-vote them, they will trust-vote me. That *is* intended and would be harmful only if trust-votes would go to harmful users, and I don't see that happening. I don't think all the votes would be distributed only among the Meta posse. What you suggest is a good idea for a smaller site, but I too think it would put too much load on mods on Stack Overflow. Massive numbers of trusted users will be needed.

Comment: @Pekka, I just removed that chunk because well, the users are supposedly trusted. Hopefully, they will act with the best intentions in mind if and when this feature request ever gets implemented.

Comment: (And I'll add this to the list of Pekka's feature-requests that will never get implemented.)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose one alternate solution how about this instead of trusted user ?

Keep the review system, allow a user to review a post if he has earned a silver/gold badge related to a question. For ex: to review a C tagged question I need to have a C Silver badge.
That way not everybody can review it, it puts additional restriction.

PS: Do let me know reason if you choose to downvote.

Comment: I'm downvoting because: 1) there are some tags where _no one_ has a bronze badge let alone a sliver and 2) Just because I don't have a C sliver badge doesn't mean that I can't tell whether a post is complete crap or not. Not knowing C may inhibit my ability to know _how_ good it is or whether it's a duplicate; it doesn't stop me from voting to close a "give me teh codez" question. My downvote indicates disagreement not that your answer is "bad" in some nebulous way :-).

Comment: Welcome to meta! Please don't be put off. It's great fun here sometimes!

Comment: Plus, I think this would seriously limit who can actually review. I've spent a lot of time on SO, and I know what a good and bad post looks like, and I don't have any silver badges in tags. Not sure this would really solve anything.

Comment: @Ben: So tweak the suggestion a bit.  If there's less than 5 with such a badge then let anyone review.  I like the idea.

Comment: @Chris, the problem with having to tweak a suggestion is that you'll have to tweak forevermore. What happens if those 5 are no longer active? On holiday? Having a break from the site in question? Do I have to alter the tags on a question to spam flag it? Might other people not do that?

Comment: Because I don't know the language I'm _a lot_ more careful about _every_ action I take on C posts. I rarely review or edit them and mostly skip them in the close votes queue if I'm in doubt. I spend about 20 times as long on an action if I'm doing something because I want to be certain. I'd rather have someone do that on the tags I'm active and help keep the site clean than them be banned. What is annoying is people without a clue doing harm because they can click a button and get out of there quick. Pekka's suggestion is meant to address this. I do not see how this answer does.