# "New Users" review queue

Tags: feature-request, review

The old First Posts review queue (I think that's what it was called) used to show you everything posted by a user with 10 or less reputation. The current one is the [first questions or answers posted by new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts). As has been complained about many times before the queue isn't necessarily working. I both agree and disagree with this and this isn't the place to go into that.

What is noticeable, however, is the extremely large number of upvotes new users get. Of course we should be [nice to new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)<sup>1</sup> but it's sometimes frustrating to see crap upvoted simply because upvoting is the quickest way method of getting the *I'm Done* button to appear.

I propose another review queue, not to fix any perceived problems with the current ones but to as Shog9 says

> ... to help introduce new users to the site - give them some feedback,
> provide some helpful edits, and flag problems for the moderators. This
> is your chance to be a part of the [<strike>S.W.A.T. Team of
> Nice</strike>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141343/a-swat-team-of-nice) welcoming posse, encouraging the new recruits and
> helping them learn the ropes.

This queue, though, would be a kind of secondary introduction to Stack Exchange. Rather than being concentrated on ensuring that the newbies didn't screw up completely I'd like something that discourages random up/down voting and encourages participation and helping new users. I imagine it as having the following actions:

#### Questions:

- flag
- edit
- close
- comment
- upvote comments
- delete (if appropriate)
- approve edits

#### Answers:

- flag
- edit
- comment (possibly including the generic ones)
- upvote comments
- recommend deletion
- approve edits

The only "quick-fix" in this list is upvoting comments but I don't mind if someone gets a badge for upvoting a constructive comment that will help a new user. All the other actions require either *work* or multiple clicks, to encourage reviewers to engage with the post.

You would *not* have the ability to vote directly in the queue. There would be a *Looks Good* button that does not require any action - maybe only available to [trusted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153502/179419) :-) - but failing that heavily rate limited.

The queue would include every post from a "new user", by this I mean everyone with less then 20 reputation. I use 20 reputation as if it's 10 it's a little useless. It takes less than 1 answer or 2 questions upvotes to reach this number. It would *not* include the first posts so there's no cross-over (and to reduce the numbers). Alternatively, it could be something like posts 2-5 of a new user if the other idea would make it too large to handle.

The emphasis of the queue is effectively on commenting, and therefore helping newer users to integrate into the site in question better. But, it would also be useful to help with any crap-cleaning.

It would have to be a 3k plus queue, but I think it might make sense to make it 4k+. There's nothing you get at 4k and it would allow new close voters to get used to their power.

<sub>1. I prefer [random's version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/9953/15).</sub>