# Document the ability to access deleted questions which we own an answer on

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, help-center

Currently, the help article about [deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) has the following text (emphasis mine):

> [...] Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and users with over 10,000 reputation. **Deleted questions will also always be visible to their authors, regardless of the author's reputation.** However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. Once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted. [...]

With the recent change to this behavior, I think the bold line should be changed to something similar to:

> Deleted questions will also always be visible to their authors **and to authors of answers on those questions**, regardless of the author's reputation.

References of the change:

- [Should I be able to access a deleted question?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16841/should-i-be-able-to-access-a-deleted-question)
- [View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k/179511#179511)
- [Lower the "see my answer to deleted question" reputation threshold for longer-time members?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230538/lower-the-see-my-answer-to-deleted-question-reputation-threshold-for-longer-ti/292758#292758)

Comment: @shog9 There is a typo in the new sentence, _Deleted questions and answers **are always be** visible to their authors_. The `be` word is probably a remnant from the old sentence.

Comment: Thanks, Dan - I updated similar text in a few other places along with this and seem to have gotten in a hurry with this one.