# What can be done with an unconstructive moderator?

Tags: support, moderators

<sub>Explicitly a support question. I do not intend to discuss the particular case here.</sub>

I have searched for an answer to this [in the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) and here, where I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151606/205264), which unfortunately discusses a protocol for moderators only. I am wondering what is the preferred thing to do when you disagree with a community moderator (not an employee of SE, Inc), without going into specific details.

Of course, the first thing to do is to ask on Meta. Now suppose the moderator in question **makes it very clear that he is not going to be constructive on this matter** (doesn't want to explain or support his decision and in no way tries to work towards an agreement) - what can be done? Are there rules or guidelines to point to that say that moderators are accountable and should explain their decisions as far as reasonably possible?

Even if other moderators agree with the particular decision and that conflict is, through them, resolved, **the issue remains that that particular moderator isn't constructive**. What can be done about that?

Should a new Meta question be opened? Or is it better to handle this in private, in chat with the other moderators, or with the SE team?

Comment: Flag, explain, or send an email to the contact address.  Or, if it's me, shut yer whining yap, ya big baby.

Comment: Is this a possible duplicate of [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/168244)

Comment: @Werner this question is not really about abuses of power, rather about the moderator's attitude. The answer may still apply though. Do you think so?

Comment: @CamilStaps: At a quick glance, it seems to.

Comment: @Werner in that case I suppose it is a duplicate. Thanks, and apologies - I didn't find that question because I initially thought it was only applicable to power abuse.

Comment: Functionally it's asking what you should do if a moderator is doing something you don't like, the specifics of what you have a problem with are irrelevant to the process of what you do about it.

Comment: @Won't _if it's me_  +1