# Does the community user only edit http to https?

Tags: support, community-user

I saw some posts that were `edited by community yesterday`. When I checked the revision history, the edit was `edited http to https`.

Does the Community User only change links from `http` to `https`, or are there **other** automated tasks created to perform this edit?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me whether you're asking if there are other things that the Community user does or if there are other processes that make automated changes to posts?

Comment: Probably part of [the https migration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time) and presumably any system tasks are attributed to community.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the edit involves [images and hyperlinks that were changed to their HTTPS counterparts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/245360). Most of the work is done automatically. Those changes are attributed to the Community user.

There is still some work to do for images that are hosted on servers that don't support HTTPS. You can find more about it in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291976/245360) of mine.

Comment: No, it's not related to images. It crawled **all** links in all posts, changing them from `http://meta.stackexchange.com/*` to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/*`.

Comment: Okay, so indeed hyperlinks as said. Didn't know which of the two exactly since I didn't see those edits.

Comment: You can see example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/151606/revisions), this also caused a [minor bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292636/automatic-http-to-https-links-replacement-job-causing-wrong-last-modified-by-i). :)

Comment: Oh, yes, I saw that post. @Sha

Answer (score -2):

The Community user is an automated bot that automatically acts to clean up Stack Exchange posts. Most of it's actions are  are documented on [its profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) or in "[Who is the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/351462)"?

Via the [Community user's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions* every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - [Remove abandoned questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006)