# Can a moderator lose moderation?

Tags: support, moderation, moderators

Can a moderator lose moderation privileges? Is it permanent?

I have seen a moderator who was last active like 2 years ago but he is still a moderator. I don't want to mention them but will they stay moderator forever?

Comment: It has happened at least once for a moderator to be demoted due to inactivity: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290286/is-andrew-barber-no-longer-a-moderator

Comment: Thaddeus on SFF hasn’t been online since April and is still one. However, two years seems ridiculous. What site was it on?

Answer (score 5):

Well, there's a few ways.

Real life tends to mug a lot of us. CMs occationally try to check in on mods who've been inactive. Some folks are contactable and decide that they want to resign. Others well... might not be.

You can also resign as a mod, or take a leave of absence.

Mods who have left in good standing can probably ask to come back as a mod.

Mods could leave in *less* [good standing as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator)

Practically though, a moderatorship is for life unless you're not able to continue or are asked to leave