# Does suspension result in automatic loss of moderator privileges?

Tags: support, moderators, account-suspension, moderator-removal

It's long been policy that [users may not stand for election as a moderator if they have been suspended anywhere on the network during the previous twelve months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/336163). If someone with a recent suspension is ineligible to be elected, it stands to reason that a *current* moderator who receives a suspension ought to lose their diamond (as they wouldn't be eligible to receive one in the first place), but I was unable to find any reference to such a scenario in [our official moderator removal processes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336173/336163).

So, if I was elected moderator on Stuff Stack Exchange last month but am suspended today from Nonsense Stack Exchange, do I lose my diamond on Stuff.SE?

- Do I lose my diamond automatically by the very fact of being suspended elsewhere on the network?
- Does being suspended elsewhere on the network automatically trigger one of the formal moderator review processes, and the result of that process will determine whether I lose my diamond?
- Do I keep my diamond, but staff and/or my fellow moderators may decide to manually begin one of the formal moderator removal processes if they deem the circumstances of my suspension to be sufficiently grave to question my ability to continue moderating?

In response to a comment by Makoto, I am aware that many forms of behavior that would lead to a suspension are of such a nature and of sufficient gravity to form the basis for a moderator removal. **My question, then, is a procedural one.** Are suspended moderators still entitled to their "due process" through the formal moderator removal processes or does diamond loss come automatically, ipso facto from the very occurrence of being suspended (that is, there is no process, no meeting, no minutes, no filings, no opportunity to be heard, etc., just a "you were suspended, your diamond has been revoked" message)?

Comment: I would imagine that being a jerk-head somewhere else on the network would still violate some portion of the Code of Conduct and thus the Moderator Agreement, and you'd lose privileges.

Comment: @Makoto I agree, but my question is whether this is automatic or whether the moderator must be put through the formal revocation procedures. It's plausible that the outcomes of a moderator removal process on one site and a suspension appeal on another could receive different dispositions (e.g. one site declines to lift the suspension but the other votes to not remove the moderator).

Comment: @RobertColumbia If it were automatic it would allow any moderator to unilaterally de-diamond someone provided that user had a regular account on their site.

Comment: There was one case where a former moderator of site A got suspended on site B, and when they later requested reinstatement on site A, their request was refused on the grounds that they'd have to wait one year after their suspension on site B expired before requesting.

Answer (score 16):

> Do I lose my diamond automatically by the very fact of being suspended elsewhere on the network?

No. It's worth pointing out that *one* of the main reasons we prevent these nominations is that they can cause a huge amount of drama during the election process. If someone's currently a moderator and they get suspended, that's unlikely to cause drama... in fact, getting removed as a moderator is likely to *cause* more drama than investigating the situation.

It's also worth mentioning that all moderators (save those who we remove under an emergency removal) get a warning the first time a specific issue is found to be worthy of action from us.

> Does being suspended elsewhere on the network automatically trigger one of the formal moderator review processes, and the result of that process will determine whether I lose my diamond?

No. It's possible that we should automate this somehow but if a moderator gets suspended, we won't be aware of it unless someone specifically mentions it to us. The reality is, there are more cases of mods getting suspended "for science" than there are of cases where mods were suspended legitimately. *In general* mods don't get suspended, so we don't even check for it.

> Do I keep my diamond, but staff and/or my fellow moderators may decide to manually begin one of the formal moderator removal processes if they deem the circumstances of my suspension to be sufficiently grave to question my ability to continue moderating?

*If* someone draws our attention to the suspension, it will likely lead to an informal investigation (as usual) which, if there are concerns found, will turn into a formal investigation. If this is a first time behavior issue, then the outcome could be any of the usual ones - anything from just a chat about what happened and some advice on how to avoid it to an official warning.

Regardless, we take each case as it comes to us. We sincerely hope (and it's largely the case) that moderators well understand the expectations of them and avoid problematic behaviors on sites they don't moderate.

Answer (score 11):

> Do I lose my diamond automatically by the very fact of being suspended elsewhere on the network?

No. I think we've scienced this before, and I've heard about an actual case where this happened (but I'm not allowed to disclose the source).

Situations to consider:

- a user's account may be suspended if it shows signs of being compromised
- a moderator erroneously suspends the wrong user (there is a rather notorious case where a moderator accidentally *destroyed* the wrong user, so this isn't too far-fetched)
- another extreme example: a rogue moderator A of site B doesn't like moderator X of site Y and decides to suspend them on site B.

Automatic removal of moderator privileges is not desired in those cases (except maybe the first). Also, the suspension will usually be reversed quickly. Note that if this would happen to a regular user, it will not prevent them from running in an election. (The Community Team can override/ignore that specific rule when made aware of the circumstances.)

I do not know the answers to your other questions, but I assume if the matter is grave enough, it only makes sense that somebody makes the Community Team aware of it, and the [Moderator Conduct Review Process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336178/295232) will be started.

Comment: I don't know if it happens here on SE, but on Wikipedia, you're not considered a *real* moderator until you block yourself while trying to block a vandal.

Comment: @Mark the SE equivalent is "you're not a real mod until a user complained about you on Meta" :)