# Moderator that was only elected and never appointed indicated as "appointed" on moderator tab

Tags: support, bug, moderators

On [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) never appointed moderator indicated as "appointed":

> [image: Grundy appointed 09.09.2020]

He won the [election](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4) amongst 10 candidates.
What's the background for this?

---

Suggested duplicates don't answer the current question. There's no data observable by regular user or moderator that could confirm that moderator was appointed instead of elected.

Comment: See [The "elected in 20XX" link on the moderators tab does not show the most recent election for moderators that have been elected more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371581/the-elected-in-20xx-link-on-the-moderators-tab-does-not-show-the-most-recent-e) - in a comment, a staff member said: *We only have space for one thing and we opted to go with the oldest record so that it's clear that moderators that were recently reinstated aren't necessarily "new" to being a moderator - up until recently, we only showed the most recent event, not the older one.*

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog on ruSO Grundy was **never** appointed, only elected once, but stated as appointed. IDK how all these suggested duplicates may answer that.

Comment: As the comment I quoted in the edited version of my comment above says, the system will always indicate the oldest record for a moderator getting their diamond. As to why the system shows them as "appointed", what I think happened here is that the election was run with only one slot and then they decided to re-run it with two slots - which explains why the date of appointment shown is one day after the election concluded that year. Keep in mind that at the time, regular staff had no tooling for elections, relying on devs, so they likely used the same tool to appoint mods to get them in.

Comment: This is really two separate questions. The first is "why is a moderator appointed one year prior to getting elected showing their prior appointment rather than their later election", which is answered in the duplicate I proposed. The second is "why is an elected moderator showing as 'appointed' one day after getting elected instead of as elected as part of that election". To avoid this getting closed as a duplicate, I'd edit the first question out.

Comment: Yep, and the oldest record is shown which means the 8:00 appointment rather than the 13:39 election will be shown.

Comment: Perhaps the tag should say *elected nem con* from the Latin nemine contradicente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I was get from the discussion in comments on question the oldest one event about when user got their diamond is used to indicate the status (appointed or elected) for moderator.

Moderator who had no competition on election is considered as "appointed", not an "elected". But even that is not the case for Grundy from Stack Overflow in Russian.

The actual reason for that that Community Manager did something wrong ([link for mod only](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55489039#55489039)) during the process of awarding the diamond. Firstly he marked the user as "appointed" and several hours later did it again but with "elected" mode.

Since there's only one oldest record per user (see above) is used to indicate status on moderators tab, the "appointed" is chosen for actually "elected" moderator.

As far as I understand only the manual changing the record in database can fix the issue.

Comment: The page *used* to show the latest record, which is why the handling staff member thought nothing of it at the time. The reason why it was changed to the oldest instead of the latest was because a moderator who took a break in response to the events of 2019 and was later reinstated complained (in private moderator space) that the page made them feel that their prior service was being disregarded. (cc @AaronBertrand)

Comment: The buttons for appoint as moderator vs make moderator by winning election are directly next to each other so it's completely possible that it was simply an error, which Nicolas later fixed. That's my reading of the situation from what I can see.

Comment: @Catija Why does employee even need to assign mod status **manually**, since winning the election based on **automatic** votes calculation?

Comment: Because, I guess, it's preferable an human being review the results, and then get in touch with them instead of a cold bot system throwing them some links. There's probably some shenanigans technically (as the mod chat room wich is its own beast disconected from the site the person is elected on) that require human intervention too. A fully automated system would be a larger surface attack to gain mod privileges too.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ you're talking about something that happened a long time ago. We don't use that method to award diamonds anymore. It isn't completely automated but it's definitely different than it was so long ago.

Comment: @Catija BTW is it hard to fix the record in database to make Grundy (great) elected again?