# How often was the moderator conduct review process used and what were the outcomes?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderators

There is [a formal process to remove moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336173/what-processes-exist-to-issue-formal-warnings-or-remove-moderators) called the moderator conduct review process. This is the main process that can remove moderators from their position.

It is pretty important for this process to work well and be used responsibly by SE to ensure the trust of the community in the company. But by design this process is not transparent itself, and it can't really be because we do not want to expose and blame individuals here. But one part that could be transparent are some statistics on how often this process has been used and what the outcomes were.

I think the relevant numbers would be how often this process was used on the whole network, and what the outcomes were. How often were moderators warned, how often was the complaint considered invalid and how often were they removed. As a statistic about the whole network it should be safe enough, it is not detailed enough to leak any private information. I think a useful timeframe would be the last year, but if another timeframe is more convenient for data collection that should be fine as well.

The main reason that I'm asking for this is that it appears that I might be understanding the process in a different way than SE does. Particularly how much evidence or complaints are necessary to trigger this process, and whether this is used to handle most complaints or only for complaints and concerns SE already validated. But in the absence of any data it's kind of hard to argue for changes to the system, so I'd like to see these rough statistics first to help judge whether my impression of how the system is used seems accurate or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since 2020, this process has been initiated 36 times, with 32 different moderators (an average of slightly less than once per month). The aggregated outcomes are 17 violations being found and 19 cases without violations being identified. It’s worth noting that, as CMs *recently* discovered by chatting with moderators, we’ve actually not been doing it *exactly* like the public MSE post says (this is on us, we documented it differently internally and have been handling it by the internal documentation, unaware that this didn’t match the public post).

The difference, specifically, is on when moderators are contacted. The process says that *“If CM1 determines no CoC or moderator agreement violation occurred, the process is concluded”* without the moderator ever being aware that it was started/happened/had a chance to weigh in. The difference is that we were not doing an in-depth investigation before contacting moderators, but rather, we would do an initial review and then judge if there was a plausible chance a violation *might have occurred*; if yes, before we got any further, we reached out to the moderator in question to get their thoughts on the situation before ever deciding if a violation had occurred or not.

No processes have been started since we discovered that inconsistency.

This year alone (to date), we’ve received and processed 97 complaints/requests to review actions moderators have taken. Each of these complaints had the potential to initiate/trigger a conduct review process, so we’re talking about a little over 30 complaints a month on average. However, we have only run 36 processes in total since 2020.

That all said, it is in our plans to revise this process to make it less convoluted and easier for moderators to understand what’s actually happening; we will, naturally, involve moderators in that redesign process when the time comes.

Comment: [What moderator removal process is followed when it's discovered that a moderator wouldn't have qualified to run for the position at the time they ran?](/q/387070)

Comment: What's a "violation"? Does that mean 17 users were de-modded? Or does it mean that CM1 in the "Discovery Phase" found a violation? Or something else?

Comment: @Laurel not necessarily that they were de-modded, no. Per the process, the first violation means only a warning, if there's a subsequent, repeat violation, *for the same reason*, that means removal.

Comment: Thanks for providing the data here. Some other aspects that might be interesting is a rough estimate of which rules of the CoC the actual violations were about. Not a detailed breakdown, just a rough impression. And for this year alone it would be nice to have the numebr of processes, so that we can compare that to the 97 complaints as we don't have that piece of information for the total duration

Comment: And, just to be 100% clear: all of the mods involved in these 17 violations were informed that their conduct had been reviewed, right?

Comment: @terdon correct, yes. We've never ran one of them in secret.

Comment: Should there be something like a transparency page that is regularly updated to keep this process as public as possible?

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow Something like the annual "Year in Moderation" reports?

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow while I'd like to see something like that, I think the problem is how transparent the detail should be.