# What happens when a moderator's account is compromised?

Tags: discussion, moderators, hacked

I know that when a regular user gets their account hacked, the account is (most likely?) put in suspension.

Does this happen for moderators as well? Are their moderator tools revoked and their account suspended, or is their a different process for mods?

Comment: There's an emergency removal process, and it's documented in [What processes exist to issue formal warnings or remove moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336173/what-processes-exist-to-issue-formal-warnings-or-remove-moderators)